# Acceso a memoria

Tags: c, punteros, manejo-de-memoria

¿Alguien me puede decir qué hace las siguientes líneas?

```
num = *((int*)(direccion+sizeof(char))); 
(*(ST_DATA*)(direccion+posTabla*sizeof(ST_DATA))).speed = num;
```

¿Las siguientes dos líneas significan lo mismo?

```
*((int*)(direccion + OFF_TABLE_KEY+sizeof(int))) = sec2;
((int*)(direccion + OFF_TABLE_KEY))[1] = sec2
```

Comment: Para poder responder con propiedad necesitaría ver la declaración de la variable `direccion`. Quizás sea también necesario ver cómo está declarada la estructura `ST_DATA`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> alguien me puede decir qué hace las siguientes líneas?

Por un lado podemos asumir que el valor típico devuelto por `sizeof(char)` es 1. Así pues y suponiendo que `direccion` va a ser un puntero:

```
char* direccion;
```

Entonces tenemos que esto:

```
direccion+sizeof(char)
```

Es aritmética de punteros y lo que hace es desplazarse una posición respecto a la dirección apuntada por `dirección`:

```
direccion
  v    
0x100 0x101 0x102
        ^
        direccion+sizeof(char)
```

Otra forma de ponerlo es la siguiente:

```
&direccion[sizeof(char)]
```

Nota el `&` inicial para recuperar la posición de memoria.

Lo que lo rodea no es más que una conversión de tipo:

```
(int*)(direccion+sizeof(char))
 ^^^^
 Conversion de char* a int*
```

Y finalmente obtenemos el valor apuntado por el puntero. Lo que pasa es que como ahora el puntero es de tipo `int`, recuperaremos 4 bytes en vez de solamente 1

```
*((int*)(direccion+sizeof(char)))
^
```

El equivalente en operaciones independientes sería:

```
char* ptr = direcciones+sizeof(char);
int* intPtr = (int*)ptr;
int num = *intPtr;
```

Y la segunda línea es equivalente pero con otro tipo de datos.

> ¿Las siguientes dos líneas significan lo mismo?

[@abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/167339/463) ya te ha respondido a esto y no creo que merezca la pena añadir nada más.

Comment: Pues releyendo mi respuesta aún se me ocurrió algo más que añadir... :-)

Comment: @abulafia sí bueno, es un matiz importante... y queda mejor todo eso unificado en tu respuesta

Answer (score 7):

> Las siguientes dos líneas significan lo mismo?
>
> ```
> *((int*)(direccion + OFF_TABLE_KEY+sizeof(int))) = sec2;
> ((int*)(direccion + OFF_TABLE_KEY))[1] = sec2
> ```

La sintaxis `puntero[entero]` equivale a `*(puntero + entero)`, y la aritmética de punteros hace que ese `entero` sea computado como `entero*sizeof(tipo)`, siendo `tipo` el apuntado por el puntero.

En el caso anterior, `puntero` sería la expresión `((int*)(direccion+OFF_TABLE_KEY))`. Aún sin saber el tipo a que apunta `direccion`, el resultado de `direccion+OFF_TABLE_KEY` nos devolverá otro puntero (a un tipo desconocido), pero ya que seguidamente el casting fuerza la interpretación de ese puntero como `int*`, entonces el poner un `[1]` después equivale a sumarle al resultado el tamaño de un entero.

Por tanto, *sí*, son equivalentes, siempre que `direccion` sea un puntero a un tipo que ocupa 1 byte (ej: `char*`). De lo contrario la dirección a la que accedería la primera expresión sería distinta, pues el compilador aún estaría multiplicando `sizeof(int)` por el tamaño del tipo apuntado por `direccion`, debido a que la expresión completa `(direccion + OFF_TABLE_KEY+sizeof(int))` es evaluada usando aritmética de punteros.

Ante la ausencia de información sobre el tipo de `direccion`, no se puede asegurar que equivalgan, pero sí puedo asegurar que las dos siguientes expresiones equivaldrían (al estar forzando el tipo de `direccion` a `char*`):

```
*((int*)((char*)direccion + OFF_TABLE_KEY+sizeof(int))) = sec2;
((int*)((char*)direccion + OFF_TABLE_KEY))[1] = sec2
```

---

> ¿Alguien me puede decir qué hace las siguientes líneas?
>
> ```
> num = *((int*)(direccion+sizeof(char))); 
> (*(ST_DATA*)(direccion+posTabla*sizeof(ST_DATA))).speed = num;
> ```

La primera ya te la ha explicado perfectamente [@eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/463/eferion). En cuanto a la segunda, de nuevo voy a hacer la hipótesis de que  `direccion` es un puntero a `char`, pues de lo contrario la expresión no tendría mucho sentido.

La expresión se comprende si suponemos que `direccion` ha sido declarado como puntero a `char`, pero en este momento lo tenemos apuntando a una zona de memoria donde hay un array de estructuras, cada una del tipo `ST_DATA`. Lo que pretende esa expresión es acceder a una de esas estructuras (la que está en lugar `posTabla`) para guardar algo en su campo `speed`.

Si `direccion` fuese un puntero a estructuras, la cosa sería tan simple como:

```
direccion[posTabla].speed = num;
```

pero el hecho de que `direccion` sea un puntero a `char` nos obliga a hacer ciertos malabarismos con los punteros y los castings. Si "forzamos" a que el compilador vea `direccion` como un puntero a `ST_DATA`, entonces podemos usar una sintaxis muy parecida a lo anterior:

```
((ST_DATA*)direccion)[posTabla].speed = num;
```

Y la línea que tú has copiado no es más que otra forma (un poco más retorcida) de hacer lo mismo, haciendo en la expresión explícita la aritmética de punteros que en la expresión que yo he puesto resolvería el compilador de forma implícita.

Aún una forma más de decir lo mismo sería:

```
(ST_DATA*)(direccion+posTabla*sizeof(ST_DATA))->speed = num;
```

en este caso si desreferenciar el puntero obtenido por la expresión, sino usando ese puntero para acceder a un miembro de la estructura. (`p->a` es equivalente a `(*p).a`)